Vigilante Movie Where one of the Foes is killed in a Grinder
I saw this American vigilante crime film in the early to mid 70`s on the big screen.
The premise (I think) is similar to the movie "Death Wish" where the main character's loved ones have been killed (accidentally or on purpose) and he is out for revenge. In this gritty film he methodically tracks down all of the people responsible (an organized crime group like the mafia) and kills them one at a time. 
The scene I remember has one of the gang members being dangled over a large grinder (maybe meat grinder) and eventually lowered to their death. The film takes place in a large modern day urban city like New York or Chicago.
I originally thought that the main character was Christopher Walken, however none of his films match the plot described above.

This is quite possibly the vigilante from The Exterminator. It's from 1980, though. 

When John Eastland's best friend, Michael Jefferson, is mugged and left permanently crippled, he decides to do something about it. Jefferson had saved Eastland's life in Vietnam and now it's time for Eastland to get revenge for his friend. Using his old Army gear he sets out on a crusade to clean up the streets of New York using the name "The Exterminator."

He lowers one of the criminals slowly into a meat grinder. You can see the scene here around 2:10:




That's the one 100%, just watched another small clip bringing back even more memories of the film (part where he pretends to have children for sale). Did you know this film or did you somehow manage to look it up.  Thank-you ... again.

The main character even sounds a fair bit like Christopher Walken.

@ErnieT. I know this one. It also appeared on Best of the Worst, which I enjoy watching (as did the sequel). Glad you found it! :)
